# How can I extract all emails from csv file using PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I need to mail my customers, and for this I have a csv file containing the customers data including emails in CSV file.

How can I use PHP to read all email addresses, put them into array, or insert them into text file (just a format I can use)

The CSV looks like this: (sample record)

```
"Date","Ref #","Time","Customer","Country","Email","Product","Product ID","Contract","Contract ID","Payment Type","Frequency","Referrer","Qty","Sale type","Adds","Total","Price","Plimus Commission","Affiliate Commssion (%)","Affiliate Commssion ($)","Tracking Id","CUSTOM1","CUSTOM2","CUSTOM3","CUSTOM4","CUSTOM5","Subscription ID","Target Balance","PayPal Comm.(main contracts)","PayPal Transaction ID","Original PayPal Transaction ID","PayPal email address"
"06/06/2008","19796287","04:06:29"," Mehmet Özekinci","Turkey","mhmtozek@gmail.com","Website Templates Pack","190830","xxxxxxxxxxx","1941602","PAYPAL","Once","xxxxxxxxxxxx","1","CHARGE","0","25","25","0","n/a","n/a"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","xxxxx Account"," "," "," ","k_anafor56@hotmail.com"
```

The file contains more than 3000+ records (CSV file). How can I find/get all emails ..@.. in PHP?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through the CSV and grab the appropriate field. You use [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to do this:

```
$emails = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $emails[] = $data[5];
}
```